# Excel Formula for the Complement of a Set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Two columns A,B and the set = {1,2,3}

```
Column A
1
2
3
3
2
1
1
3
2
.
.
.
```

How to write a formula to return the complement for Column B like

```
2,3
1,3
1,2
1,2
1,3
2,3
2,3
1,2
1,3
.
.
.
```

Does anyone knows an excel formula that I can use to return the complement? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @all Thanks for the contributions. I use Excel 2013 and unfortunately nothing from the answers worked for me. Also, my bad that some contributors might get confused and the items in the set should be treated as individual string and I didn't mean three consecutive integers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
=LET(k,{1,2,3},MAP(A1:A9,LAMBDA(λ,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(k,k<>λ)))))
```

Obviously you can replace the hard-coded set - `{1,2,3}` - with a reference to a range of cells containing those values if you prefer.

Comment: Why not `FILTER(k,k<>λ)`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Oops, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=PY(
    [', '.join(map(str,list(filter(lambda x:x!=int(y),[1,2,3])))) for y in xl("A1:A9")[0]]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:
`=LET(a,A1:A9,u,UNIQUE(a),MAP(a,LAMBDA(b,TEXTJOIN(",",,TOCOL(IFS(u<>b,u),2)))))`

I used `UNIQUE(a)` so, no matter what type of data (text/number) or the number of distinct uniques, this will adapt.

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(a,A1:A9, n,SEQUENCE(3), MAP(a,LAMBDA(m, ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(n,n<>m)))))
```

[image]